# Cakephp 3.4.14 Exception: Shell class for "Serve" could not be found

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

here is my shell snip

```
 Maan@DESKTOP-TNA7PJU MINGW64 /d/xampp1/htdocs/app
$ bin/cake serve
Exception: Shell class for "Serve" could not be found. in [D:\xampp1\htdocs\app\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Console\ShellDispatcher.php, line 327]

Maan@DESKTOP-TNA7PJU MINGW64 /d/xampp1/htdocs/app
$ cd ../pocketpa-git-clone000000/

Maan@DESKTOP-TNA7PJU MINGW64 /d/xampp1/htdocs/pocketpa-git-clone000000 (master)
$ bin/cake serve
Exception: Shell class for "Serve" could not be found. in [D:\xampp1\htdocs\pocketpa-git-clone000000\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Console\ShellDispatcher.php, line 327]
Warning Error: file_put_contents(D:\xampp1\htdocs\pocketpa-git-clone000000\logs\cli-error.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in [D:\xampp1\htdocs\pocketpa-git-clone000000\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Log\Engine\FileLog.php, line 133]

PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(D:\xampp1\htdocs\pocketpa-git-clone000000\logs\cli-error.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp1\htdocs\pocketpa-git-clone000000\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Log\Engine\FileLog.php on line 133
```

last night i shut down my pc and in morning when i restart i am facing this issue
cakephp version 3.4.14
php 5.6.36
and having this problem when wants to start project

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad i was messed up with diffferent projects i was working on Laravel Projects and using frequently

`php artisan serve`

This command will start a development server at http://localhost:8000:
when i come back to CakePhp Project i was messed up and trying

`bin\cake serve`

command to start local server for cakephp environment http://localhost:8765/
thats make me so much trouble
But the orignal command to run CakePhp Sever on LocalHost is

`bin\cake server`

here you can get more details https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#development-server